# add multiple data on a custom listview

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listview

I have a mainactivity which calls a fragment to load a new xml with listview on it that calls another xml for the items on the listview. How can I put multiple data on it. I can only add one data on the textview. here is my fragment that loads the data

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

    protected ProgressBar mProgressBar;
    protected JSONArray blogPostData;

    protected String[] blogPostTitle;
    protected String[] blogPostDate;
    protected String[] blogPostAuthor;

    private ListView listView;

    private View rootView;

    public HomeFragment(){}

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
        listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.article_list);
        mProgressBar = (ProgressBar) rootView.findViewById(R.id.progressBarHome);

        ArticleController articleController = new ArticleController(mListener);
        articleController.execute();

        return rootView;
    }

    MyListener mListener = new MyListener(){

        @Override
        public void onComplete(JSONArray result) {

            blogPostData = result;
            updateArticleList();

            List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(blogPostTitle));
            List<String> stringList1 = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(blogPostDate));
            List<String> stringList2 = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(blogPostAuthor));


            ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.layout_listview_article, R.id.titleTV, stringList);
            arrayAdapter1.add(getActivity(), R.layout.layout_listview_article, R.id.authorTV, stringList1);
            arrayAdapter1.add(getActivity(), R.layout.layout_listview_article, R.id.authorTV, stringList2);

            listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter1);

            mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);


        }
    };

    protected void updateArticleList(){

        try {

            blogPostTitle = new String[blogPostData.length()];
            String[] blogPostDate = new String[blogPostData.length()];
            String[] blogPostAuthor = new String[blogPostData.length()];
            for (int i = 0; i < blogPostData.length(); i++)
            {
                JSONObject jsonObject = blogPostData.getJSONObject(i);
                String title = jsonObject.getString("title");
                title = Html.fromHtml(title).toString();
                blogPostTitle[i] = title;

                String date = jsonObject.getString("created_at");
                date = Html.fromHtml(date).toString();
                blogPostDate[i] = date;

                String author = jsonObject.getString("author");
                author = Html.fromHtml(author).toString();
                blogPostAuthor[i] = author;
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You have to create a Custom Adapter.

Comment: do you want to parse multiple images and tetx?/

Comment: @rahshree Yes I want to parse multiple text and images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, You have to read this [tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html) which simply extends ArrayAdapter and create view according to requirement and then look this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8166497/custom-adapter-for-list-view), it explains almost all things those you want to implement.